# Как сформировать запрос к различным API в React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Через fetch формирую запрос к API, как достать Json ответа из Promise

```
const URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + this.props.latitude + '&lon=' + this.props.longitude + '&appid=98e5bfeb477c9bec9f5ee8de192eaed8'
        const query = fetch(URL).then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

Или подскажите как правильно формировать запросы в React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать так

```
 fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.props.latitude}&lon=${this.props.longitude}&appid=98e5bfeb477c9bec9f5ee8de192eaed8`)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log('Request successful', data);
        return data;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error)
      });
```

Возможно но не обязательно, что вам понадобятся прописывать method и headers

```
  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.props.latitude}&lon=${this.props.longitude}&appid=98e5bfeb477c9bec9f5ee8de192eaed8`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `any`,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log('Request successful', data);
        return data;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error)
      });
```

В реакт лучше всего использовать fetch в Redux. 
Не сохраняйте fetch в переменную, что бы получить данные от запроса. 
fetch возвращает промис узнайте больше о промисах https://learn.javascript.ru/promise .

В реакт без redux вы можете делать например так

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Hello extends Component {
  state = {
    temp: "3",
    pressure: "",
    temp_min: "",
    temp_max: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.props.latitude}&lon=${this.props.longitude}&appid=98e5bfeb477c9bec9f5ee8de192eaed8`)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(
      (result) => {
        let { temp, pressure, temp_min, temp_max } = result.main
        this.setState({
          temp,
          pressure,
          temp_min,
          temp_max
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error)
      });
  }
  render() {
    return  <ul>
      <li>temp: {this.state.temp} </li>
      <li>pressure: {this.state.pressure} </li>
      <li>temp_min: {this.state.temp_min} </li>
      <li>temp_max: {this.state.temp_max} </li>
    </ul>
  }
}
```